# Is there a word that means to see something but not be able to describe?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the feeling or situation you are in when you can't find words to describe something you experience. Similar to being speechless but more specifically in regard to seeing some sort of natural phenomenon that just blows you away. I'm working on a name for my film company and I want to tap into the idea that some things must be seen because words cannot properly describe them. Any help would be really appreciated.

Alternatively, is there some combination of roots that can be put together to form a new word?

Comment: _Gobsmacked_ has probably already been taken.

Comment: 'sensory overload' comes to mind.

Comment: Why did you eliminate "indescribable" (synonym "unutterable") ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like **beyond reality** ?

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you're looking for is either *ineffable* or *euphoria* (or a combination of both).

> INEFFABLE:
>   /ɪnˈɛfəb(ə)l/
>   too great or extreme to be expressed or described in
>   words.
>
> Via: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ineffable

AND

> EUPHORIA:
>   /juːˈfɔːrɪə/
>   a feeling or state of intense excitement and happiness.
>
> Via: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphoria

Answer (score 0):

Such concept may be evoked by *dreamlike*.

*Definition from dictionary.com*:

> - a succession of images, thoughts, or emotions passing through the mind during sleep.
> - an object seen in a dream.
> - an involuntary vision occurring to a person when awake.
> - an aspiration

Answer (score 0):

I would go with *awed*, perhaps some wouldn't consider this to be speechless but that is a fault of modern hyperbole.

> *[Awed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/awed)* - Filled with awe or wonder

Likewise Gobsmacked was a fine answer

> *[Gobsmacked](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gobsmacked?q=Gobsmacked)* — Utterly astonished; astounded
>
> *[Flabbergast](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flabbergast?q=flabbergasted)* — Surprise (someone) greatly; astonish
>
> *[Dumbstruck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dumbstruck)* — So shocked or surprised as to be unable to speak (also called dumbstricken)
>
> *[Nonplus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonplus)* — Surprise and confuse (someone) so much that they are unsure how to react

Also, it is a fairly common thing [now](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheWorldIsJustAwesome?from=Main.TheyShouldHaveSentAPoet) to whisper *they should have sent a poet* in a situation where you are at a loss for words.

Comment: Shocked is better than dumbstruck.  Go with shocked.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oxford Dictionaries Online definition of *transcendent*, not from the OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/transcendent):

> adjective
>
> beyond or above the range of normal or physical human experience

This word captures the sense that meaning is outside of one's reach. As a name for a film company, the name Transcendence Global Media (transcendenceglobalmedia.org) is already taken.

Comment: Please stop claiming things are from the OED that are not. Also please provide a proper reference and link.

Comment: You’re welcome. It’s because we need to have any text that’s copied from elsewhere properly attributed; there are several meta posts about this. When I can find the original source people are quoting, I fill it in for them, but when I don’t know where they got something from, I have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

*Do I get a commission if I hit the nail on the head?*

Wonderment

Bedazzled / bedazed

Enchantment / enchanted

Beatitude

Exalted

Becharmed

Sublime

Entrancing

Benefit performance

Bestill (to cause to be still)

Bethrall, bethralled, enthralled

Astounded

Thunderstruck

Wordless

Beyond the pale

Beyond compare

Sans pareil

Also try translating "sans pareil" from French to English, all those results look promising.

Answer (score 0):

- unfathomable
- bewildering

Both seem appropriate, and seem to share a clear connection with **Unreal** Engine.

Other words to consider:

- enigmatic
- profound
- unparalleled
- unrivaled
- unmatched

Answer (score -1):

What about:

- inexplicable
- ineffable
- aesthetic
- dumb-founded
- groping/fumbling for words
- ravishing/exquisite

— and many more. However most of the words are used for positive end results.